# Grails controllers pass parameters

Tags: grails, parameters, controllers

My controller is the folowing:

```
def participated = {
  def temp = ConferenceUser.get(params.temp)

  def prizes = Prizes.findAllByConferenceUser(temp) // find all rooms where current computer is
  def subms = Submissions.findAllByConferenceUser(temp) // find all rooms where current computer is

  [temp: temp, priz: prizes, subm: subms]
}
```

But somehow, when I successfully update a conference value, I wanna go back to the initial page (participated) but I don't know how to pass back the `params.temp`. (if I do a simple redirect, as the controller is expecting `params.temp`, it will give me an error because I cannot search prizes with a null object as parameter. So, imagine my update controller is the following:

```
def update = {
  def saveParamshere = params.temp
  ...
  ...
  (code here)
  ...
  ...

  redirect(action: "participated", params: [temp: saveParamshere])
}
```

This code isn't working. How can I successfully go back to my main page and pass in `params.temp` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the problem may be, that you are calling `update` action by submitting form (I suppose). Maybe you are not passing `temp` value from that form? You can do it by embedding `temp` as hidden input field into form, or apply it to url by `param` attribute on form tag.

Using hidden field it might be something like this (in your view file):

```
<g:form controller="somecontroller" action="update">
  (...)
  <g:hiddenField name="temp" value="${temp}" />
  (...)
</g:form>
```

Using `params` attribute:

```
<g:form controller="somecontroller" action="update" params="[temp : temp]">
  (...)
</g:form>
```

I didn't test any of these so there might be some issues, especially in the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could put the params in the flash scope, which lives for two requests, or put them in the session and retrieve them that way.

Here is a link to the grails docs on usage of flash scope:

[Grails - Controllers - Controller Scopes](http://www.grails.org/Controllers+-+Controller+Scopes)

Comment: Yep, flash scope lives for current request and the next one (i.e. survives redirects). So doing flash.temp = params.temp in the update action should mean you can access flash.temp in the redirected action.

Comment: From the docs: "Flash scope is a concept introduced by Rails. It is a temporary store for attributes which need to be available for this request and the next request only. Afterwards the attributes are cleared. This is useful for setting a message directly before redirection, for example"

Comment: my bad, I forgot that it survives redirects.